# What does "Method [show] does not exist" mean?

Tags: methods, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel 4 and trying to figure out why I'm getting an error saying that Method [show] does not exist.

*I do not have a method named "show"* and can only imagine that this is an internal, Laravel method but I do not know how to affect this or what could have done this. Any thoughts or help on this would be incredibly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for two days now and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

View:

```
<li><a href="{{ URL::route('account-sign-in') }}">Sign in</a></li>
```

Route:

```
/*Sign In (GET)*/
    Route::get('/account/sign-in', array(
        'as'    => 'account-sign-in',
        'uses'  => 'AccountController@getSignIn'
    ));
```

AccountController:

```
class AccountController extends BaseController { 
  public function getSignIn(){ 
    return View::make('user.signIn'); 
  } 

  public function postSignIn(){ 
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array( 'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required' ) ); 
    if($validator->fails()){ /*Redirect to the sign in page*/ 
      return Redirect::route('account-sign-in') ->withErrors($validator) ->withInput();
    } 
    else { /*Attempt user sign in*/ 
      $remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;
      $auth = Auth::attempt(array( 'email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'), 'active' => 1 ), $remember); 
      if($auth){ 
        /*Redirect to the intended page*/ return Redirect::intended('/'); 
      } 
      else {
        return Redirect::route('account-sign-in')->with('global', 'Email/password wrong, or account not activated.'); 
      } 
    } 
    return Redirect::route('account-sign-in') ->with('global', 'There was a problem signing you in.'); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: show us the xdebug stacktrace.

Comment: Not sure what that is. Here is the last 5 events - [2014-03-16 20:44:07] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'syntax error, unexpected '}'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\local\tbf3\app\controllers\AccountController.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
[2014-03-16 20:45:01] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'BasesController' not found' in C:\xampp\htdocs\local\tbf3\app\controllers\AccountController.php:3

Comment: I noticed it says "Class BasesController' not found. I do not have any controllers named BasesController nor do I have any that reference it. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's the debug messages that come up with the error message:
19. BadMethodCallException
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php266
18. Illuminate\Routing\Controller __call
<#unknown>0
17. AccountController show
<#unknown>0
16. call_user_func_array
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php231
15. Illuminate\Routing\Controller callAction
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php93
14. Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher call
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php62

Comment: @gv0029 you need to include the entire AccountController, or at least the Class declaration line, as well as any other relevant pieces of code

Answer (score 1):

> What does “Method [show] does not exist” mean?

Code provided in your question doesn't shows anything about `show()` method, anyways. According to to your comments you didn't extend the `BaseController` but all your controlers should extend the BaseController and the `BaseController` should extend the `Controller` so this is how your `BaseController` should look like (By default):

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

   /**
    * Setup the layout used by the controller.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }
}
```

Your controller should extend it like this:

```
class AccountController extends BaseController {

    // Define all of your methods
    // including show() if you are using it

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately that is not the case as I do have my controllers set up as you pointed out above.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what is the case then, all I got this from your question and comments :-)

Comment: Normally laravel is pretty straight forward: you make a view, you make a route, and you make a controller. The above route, controller, and view all seem to make sense to me (I only pasted the parts of each that were pertaining to this view) but yet something is not working. So my next thought is that there is something more going on here then the simple view->route->controller dynamic. I was wondering if anyone had any thoughts. Though of course it could be that I have an obvious error in what I wrote above and just didn't see it. But thoughts and input would be welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just have a typo on the first line of your AccountController

It probably says `class AccountController extends BasesController {`

`BasesController` should be `BaseController`

Comment: I thought the same thing but already checked that: 

<?php

class AccountController extends BaseController {
 
 public function getSignIn(){...

Comment: @gv0029 try running the command `php artisan dump-autoload` in your project root. Autoloaded classes such as controllers/models can sometimes cause bugs if you change their class names without dumping the autoload.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. I had previously listed a (now deprecated) resource that was causing a collision in the routes.php file.

```
Route::resource('scheduler', 'SchedulerController');
Route::get('scheduler/notices', 'SchedulerController@notices');
```